# How to save youtube videos with UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum?

Tags: ios, video, youtube, save

I am able to save the local video (which I have copied to code) to my 
Photo Album with the help of `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

I want to save the you tube video into the Photo album. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: youtube has not given right to download its videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't save YouTube videos locally because of 2 main reasons:

1. YouTube do not allow users to download videos to local devices.
2. There is no appropriate API in iOS for this.